# How to enable change/delete ForeignKey entity in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Django admin for ForeignKey fields renders a small "plus" link that allows to create a new entity.

[image]

And it looks like it is also able to render links for change/delete ForeignKey objects

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/related_widget_wrapper.html#L13

But no example from the documentation shows how to make this functionality available. Is there any non documented option?

Comment: i use django 1.8.4 .when i login with supperuser ,  i see add and edit links but delete is invisble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the code of the [BaseModelAdmin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L193) class and the [RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L241) class.

In `BaseModelAdmin`, it is first ensured that the user has permission to add, change or delete objects of the related model.

In `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`, to change or delete a related object it is also ensured that the relation is not a many-to-many. Moreover, a related object cannot be deleted if the cascade delete is enabled for this relationship.

The permissions are by default True, I assume you would know if if you had changed them? If indeed you didn't, the reason why you cannot change the related object might be that you overrid the [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) attribute in the admin model, or the [`get_readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) method.

Once you can see the change button, you will probably not yet see the delete button as the cascading is the default. You can change this by setting the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) attribute when creating the foreign key.

Comment: thanks, i missed requirement for `on_delete` ForeignKey field option.

Answer (score 2):

look at `__init__` function of class `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` in `django/contrib/admin/widgets.py`:

```
self.can_delete_related = not multiple and not cascade and can_delete_related
```